# Are CVOpenGL[ES]TextureCaches incompatible with floating point formats?

Tags: ios, macos, opengl, opengl-es-2.0, core-video

On OSX10.4/iOS5 and onwards you can optimize your texture uploads and downloads using  `CVOpenGL[ES]TextureCaches`.

Instead of uploading textures with `glTexImage2D` and reading from the frame buffer with `glReadPixels`, you use a `CVOpenGL[ES]TextureCache` to translate your texture/FBO operations  into the language of CoreVideo `CVPixelBuffers`.

This works perfectly well with byte (and probably short) sized integer formats, but, apart from a fancy YUV pixel format, floats are decidedly under-represented in [Core Video's Pixel Formats](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1501/_index.html).

Does this mean I can't use `GL_FLOAT` textures and render targets with `CVOpenGL[ES]TextureCaches`?